# iterator_count returning 5 when there are only 3 files

Tags: php

I have 3 files in a folder.

Why is this function returning `5`?

```
function GetFileCount("./Images/banner/")
{
    return iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator($directory));
}
```

Comment: Because it also counts `./` and `../`

Comment: It counts the current folder( the dot -> .) and the parent (two dots -> ..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.` (current directory) and `..` (one-up directory) will also be counted.

Therefore, you'll always end up with (files in folder)+2.

You to get around this, you can use `->isDot()` [as per the DirectoryIterator documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php).

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('./Images/banner') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi it is because it adds the following ".." and "."